Can I have a shared application.properties file accross profiles?
I want to separate my logback config by profiles "local" and "sandbox". But I want to share a application.properties accross profiles "local" and "sandbox". There is also another profiles like "prod" , . . .
How can I do it?

just add an application.properties as that will always be loaded.

@M.Deinum I think if doing so, another profiles wil be affected also.

application.properties should contain the defaults which you can override or complement in other profiles

I guess you want to create separate logback configuration files for each profile.

Create configuration files like logback-sandbox.xml.
Create a common application.properties file, which will be shared across local and sandbox:
You need to create profile/environment specific properties file and in that properties file mention property like spring.profiles.active=sandbox
Lastly, create the xml file. Make sure to mention the contextName field [Sandbox, Prod etc.].

I hope it is successful.

You can create profile-specific configuration files, like application-local.properties and application-sandbox.properties, where you define the logback configurations for "local" and "sandbox" profiles respectively.
Place the shared properties in application.properties, which will be loaded across all profiles. The application-local.properties and application-sandbox.properties files will inherit from application.properties and can override specific settings as needed.
